# Where to put code that depends on other external 3rd party services?

Tags: .net

I'm developing an application using the repository pattern in .Net, as part of my business logic an SMS has to be sent. Where should the code for this go so that during my tests an SMS is not actually sent?

Comment: You mean, SMS should not be sent when unit tests are running ?

Comment: This is kind of vague, but usually you would have an SMS Sender service, which you would mock in your tests.

Comment: what does this have to do with the repository pattern?

Comment: @Ciprian Are you sure I should mix repositories and services like that?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Definitely not, the sms is not the main focus of the logic and it costs me money every time!

Comment: @Fran is right, this has nothing to do with repository. You can put it in a SMS repository if you like. The idea is that in your tests you must use a mock/stub of that class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

External interactions such as sending email, sending SMS, calling third party web service etc should be behind the business layer. You can think of them as parallel layer to the repositories.

Business layer should be responsible to interact with the external services but not directly of course.

There should be a wrapper service written and business layer should be dependent on the wrapper service rather then the actual external endpoint.

Consider following example:

```
public interface ISmsService
{
    bool SendSms(string toNumber, string messageBody);
}

public class TwilioSmsService : ISmsService
{
     public bool SendSms(string toNumber, string messageBody)
     {
         // Send SMS using twilio
         return true;
     }
}

public interface ICustomerRepository
{
    Customer GetCustomer(string customerId);
}

public class CustomerRepository : ICustomerRepository
{
    public Customer GetCustomer(string customerId)
    {
         Expression<Func<Customer, bool>> criteria = cust => cust.CustomerId.Equals(customerId);
         return return Context.Set<Customer>.FirstOrDefault(criteria);
    }
}

public class OrderService
{
    private IOrderRepository orderRepository;
    private ISmsService smsService;
    public ICustomerRepository customerRepository;

    public OrderService(IOrderRepository orderRepository, ICustomerRepository customerRepository, ISmsService smsService)
    {
         this.orderRepository = orderRepository;
         this.customerRepository = customerRepository;
         this.smsService = smsService;
    }

    public void PlaceOrder(Order orderObj, string customerId)
    {
          this.orderRepository.SaveOrder(orderObj);
          var customer = this.customerRepository.GetCustomer(customerId);
          this.smsService.SendSms(customer.MobileNo, "You order is received successfully");
    }
}
```

Now you can unit test OrderService without actually sending SMS. You need to create mock of ISmsService and other dependencies of OrderService.

Note : above code is purely an example. You can have your own idea around this to make it working for your specific needs.

This should give you hint about how you can arrange your layers and unit test them.

Comment: Awesome, a great answer thank you. Slightly off topic but could you give an opinion on me using such a generic repository in my gist here: https://gist.github.com/jakeam/6ccada92025389263d12e91412182cd1

Comment: This works, but ties the order service to an external system that may be up or down.  Do you really want to stop processing if you can send an email? CQRS seems like a good fit for decoupling your domain logic from services like these.

Comment: Agreed... but if the use case of SMS service not working is handled properly and it should not stop the system. Monitoring the service, handling errors and exception and properly logging mechanism should make things easy to understand, debug and fix. Again what I shared is a sample example revolving around the question. There are N number of ways to integrate with external services based on the requirement and CQRS could be best suited here. I am not much familiar with that so it didn't come in my mind.

Comment: @JacobMason Looked at your code. It's is over generalised. I would recommend to have repository creating filter criteria based on the values provided by the Manager. Manager or service should be handling the business logic such as validation of entities, calculations etc but they should not be creating Expressions or queries to be executed by repository. Let the repository take care of creating criteria or query based on the underlaying data access layer. the current approach will fail if you have to fall back to ADO.NET (bad example :( ). Current repositories are not made for that situation.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Are you able to provide an example at all? I presume in the case case of my example I would have a PersonRepository or PersonService, could you give an example of how it would look?

Comment: I have changed the answer to have CustomerRepository class which takes care of creating criteria to be used as filter. This can be improved a lot but it wouldn't be possible to discuss in details here. You better look at repository pattern blogs and articles and get the best from them and use them as per your need.